# How to redirect to our URL after payment completion in 2checkout payment gateway.

Tags: payment, 2checkout

How to set return_url in 2checkout payment gateway to redirect page to our site after completion of payment process?

Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You can setup your approved URL either at the account level (on the Site Management Page), at the product level (if you are using 2Checkout's Plug and Play cart) or you can pass it in with each sale using the `x_receipt_link_url` parameter.

If you choose to pass the URL path in for each sale, the domain that you pass must match the domain registered with your 2Checkout account.

More information on the 2Checkout return process can be found in [How Does The Return Process Work?](https://www.2checkout.com/blog/knowledge-base/merchants/tech-support/passbacks-and-returns/how-does-the-return-process-work/).

Answer (score 0):

```
You can setup your approved URL in your 2checkout account using Site Management
click on **Given links back to my website  radio button** Then after setup
```

Approved URL

```
where is your 2co_ipn.php file and set success file name
http://localhost/payment/success.php
```